# using simplexml_load_file() to get attributes from xml file for Amazon Affiliate API

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, simplexml

I am using Amazon Affiliate API here. I am fairly new to all of this actually.

I have the PHP code to generate a working URL for products, however I am having issues extracting data from that url's generated xml. I am looking to return the FormattedPrice from the xml.

Here is an example of the xml file:
https://pastebin.com/HnttEVfv

Here is my code trying to pull the "FormattedPrice". Neither of the examples below are working and are just returning empty values.

Sidenote: $request_url is a full http:// valid url of the xml file.

```
$getxml = simplexml_load_file($request_url); 
$price = $getxml->ItemLookupResponse->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->ListPrice['FormattedPrice'];
```

Nor does

```
$price = $getxml->ItemLookupResponse->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->FormatedPrice;
```

Comment: Does file_get_contents($request_url) return something?

Comment: If it does properly return the XML's content as string, you could just simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($request_url)).

Comment: var_dump($getxml); dumps however when I try going to "FormattedPrice" I can't seem to get the code of the price to pull from the XML.file_get_contents($request_url)  returns a string of the entire xml yes; however wrapping in in load string does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Every XML document has a single "root element". In your example, that top-level element is `<ItemLookupResponse>`.

When you load the document in SimpleXML, the first object it gives you is that root element. You then access *chlidren* of that element with the `->ElementName` notation.

So instead of `$getxml->ItemLookupResponse->Items` you should write `$getxml->Items`.

Comment: I am still getting an empty return.